# anylogic: detect mouse click pressed and release events

Tags: anylogic

On any image or many other objects there is an onClick action that I can use. But I am interested in the mouse click pressed and release events, as user is dragging the mouse in between these events. Finally I want to capture the coordinates at which click happened and at which release happened. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking click-pressed and release events are not possible anymore since AnyLogic switched to browser-based animations (used to be possible in AnyLogic 6 with Java Swing).

Getting click coordinates, however, is possible. Just drag in a rectangle (or some other shape) and you have a handle as below. Note that these are relative to the shape's position:
[image]

Comment: Hi @AmitKumar , please upvote the answer, if it was useful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote :)